# StyledCellLabelProvider does not react to foreground erasure

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jface

Consider the following working example of a `TableViewer`:

```
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final ColumnLabelProvider labelProvider = new ColumnLabelProvider();

    final TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(shell,
            SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);
    viewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());

    final TableViewerColumn viewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
    viewerColumn.setLabelProvider(labelProvider);
    viewerColumn.getColumn().setText("");
    viewerColumn.getColumn().setWidth(100);

    viewer.setInput(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3"));

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
```

It's a simple table with the elements "1", "2" and "3". Now I want to draw the table items myself, so I added the following line:

```
    viewer.getTable().addListener(SWT.EraseItem, e -> e.detail &= ~SWT.FOREGROUND);
```

...and a paint listener, but to understand my problem it's sufficient to see that now the items are not shown (which is correct).

So now I wanted to add a `StyledCellLabelProvider` to style the cell without modifying existing code:

```
    final StyledCellLabelProvider styledLabelProvider = new StyledCellLabelProvider() {

        @Override
        public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
            labelProvider.update(cell);
            cell.setBackground(cell.getControl().getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
            super.update(cell);
        }
    };
    // [snip][snap]

    viewerColumn.setLabelProvider(styledLabelProvider);
```

Funnily enough, *now* the items are shown again, even though I tried to remove them in the `SWT.EraseItem` listener.

Can anybody tell me why? And ideally how to fix it?

Comment: If you use StyledCellLabelProvider you should override its `erase`, `measure` and `paint` methods since they are already using the EraseItem, MeasureItem and PaintItem listeners.

Comment: @greg-449 It doesn't work with the `e.detail &= ~SWT.FOREGROUND` in `erase(Event, Object)` either.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do here. `StyledCellLabelProvider` expects you to use the cell `setBackground`, `setForeground`, `setText` and maybe `setStyleRange` calls in the `update` method. I don't think how it interacts with other erase, measure and paint listeners is defined.

Comment: @greg-449 I guess it boils down to: For a `ColumnLabelProvider` I can disable the drawing of the forground with `event.detail &= ~SWT.FOREGROUND`. I want to do the same for a `StyledCellLabelProvider`. (Because the current API works under the assumption that the `TableItem`s text is set and I want to change as little as possible while switching from one label provider to the other.)

Comment: @SteffiS. could you please tell me why you are using paint listener and SWT.EraseItem to set background and foreground color of Cell? Do you have any specific requirement for your project? We can still set background and foreground color of  cell even if we use StyledCellLabelProvider. please reply, So that I can provide you the sample code snippet

Comment: @ShrirangKumbhar I set the background color because I want to fake a selection that way. And not related: I remove the foreground  because the default display of the text does not suit me, so a paint listener draws it (and it uses `TableItem#getText()` to figure out what to draw).